# How to prevent SELECTing extra fields in a JOINed .includes()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I’m trying to implement parametrized grouping to a report. A simplified example of what I’m trying to achieve:

```
observation_query = Observation.includes(:reporter).order("reporters.name")

if params[:group_results]
  observation_query = observation_query
  .select("DATE(observations.created_at) AS created_at, AVG(value) AS value")
  .group("DATE(observations.created_at)", :reporter_id)
end

observation_query.each do |observation|
  puts "#{observation.reporter.name} #{observation.created_at}: #{observation.value}"
end
```

When grouping is not used, or if I remove the ordering, the results are as expected. But when both ordering and grouping are used, the query generated due to having to achieve the eager loading with JOINs is:

```
SELECT DATE(observations.updated_at) AS updated_at, AVG(value) AS value,
`observations`.`id` AS t0_r0,
`observations`.`value` AS t0_r1,
`observations`.`reporter_id` AS t0_r2,
...
`observations`.`created_at` AS t0_r6,
`observations`.`updated_at` AS t0_r7,
`reporters`.`id` AS t1_r0, 
...
FROM `observations` INNER JOIN `reporters` ON `reporters`.`id` = `observations`.`user_id`
GROUP BY DATE(observations.created_at), `observations`.`reporter_id`
ORDER BY reporters.name
```

..which gives the MySQL error `'observations.id' isn't in GROUP BY`. How do I prevent selection of columns which are not used for grouping?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with `preload`, which seems to work similarly to `includes`, with the difference that JOINs and SELECTs of the primary query are controlled manually.

```
observation_query = Observation.joins(:pulse).preload(:reporter).order("reporters.name")

if params[:group_results]
  observation_query = observation_query
  .select(:reporter_id, "DATE(observations.created_at) AS created_at, AVG(value) AS value")
  .group("DATE(observations.created_at)", :reporter_id)
end
```

The thing about this solution is that table `reporter`s is queried *twice*, first JOINed for ordering and then a second query that SELECTs the values for filling the associated records. Because the equivalent of `reporters.name` is indexed in my actual case, this is good enough, but the optimal solution would generate a single query, so I’m not marking this as the answer.